# java httpexchange response to jquery ajax call is empty

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to do a post to a java program I've written (that implements com.sun.net.httpserver.httphandler). I've got a problem that I can do the ajax call and see it get caught in the java program, however in Firebug, the response is empty.

Here is my ajax code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/applications/nvn",
    data: "command=GetNVN",
    dataType:"text",
    success: function(msg){
    var fdsa;
    fdsa++;
    init(msg);
    },
    error: function( foo ){
    var fff;
    fff++;
    }
});
```

And here is my server code.

```
    Headers headers = t.getRequestHeaders();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entries = headers.entrySet();

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entries)
      response.append(entry.toString() + "\n");

    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
    os.close();
```

The error handler in the jQuery code has an object that says "error" in it.
One additional detail, my server is on port 80 so as far as I know, there is no cross domain querying going on... I think.

Any suggestions are appreciated,

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I was making a cross domain ajax call. I just changed the content-type to jsonp and it worked.